# How to do XSLT 2.0 transformation with C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Is it possible to use XSLT 2.0 transformation with native .net framework ?

I know it's possible with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: (and from that, I suspect http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/ is your best bet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no XSLT 2.0 processor offered by Microsoft**.

An XSLT 2.0 processor that claims to be written especially to be used in .NET is **[XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com)**.

Another very popular XSLT 2.0 processor is **[Saxon 9.x](http://www.saxonica.com)**, which, although written in Java, has a special .NET version.

Comment: both are quite slow, so best is sticking to 1.0 atm :(

Comment: @Jaster: I don't have much experience with XQSharp, but Saxon has been so optimized that I strongly disagree with such a statement. Also, people use XSLT 2.0 for its wealth of new features and a few milliseconds do not match in 99% of the cases.

Comment: @Jaster: Any misused tool can be slow.

Comment: Don't blame me, just do some performance testing with xslt 1.0. Base .NET vs Saxon od XQSharp. It's not "some milliseconds".

@Alejandro so using them for xslt is worng? Those tools intend to cook coffee?

Comment: Just to add some data, in our case xslt 1.0 takes 450ms and saxon takes 750ms.

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann, I am sure that the same, written in Assembler, would take 20-30 ms. But XSLT 2.0 is already quite old. At present people are using XSLT 3.0 / XPath 3.0. Maybe in the three years since this reply was written, Saxon achieved even further optimization (to be found in its latest Saxon9.5.x processor).

Comment: I totally agree Dimitre. I was just giving "real life" timings in case it could help people. Btw, the bench was done using Saxon 9.5 and the performance results were good from our point of view.

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann, it is good when testing Saxon to use the "repeat" argument with a value at least 3-4, otherwise the time is unrealistically bigger as it includes the time for loading the JVM (IKVM).

Answer (score 2):

I disagree that XQSharp (or for that matter Saxon) is slow.  While neither currently compile to MSIL, both have good optimizers.  I know from first-hand experience thatlarge grouping tasks can be faster with XQSharp than with XslCompiledTransform.